# HTML5 canvas drawImage or CSS background url

Tags: css, html, dom, canvas, background

I have a question, wich one have the best performance in webBrowsers?
drawing a canvas with the given url image "context.drawImage(...)" or just using css with "background:url('...')".
(both images filling the entire webPage as a wallpaper)

For big images (wallpapers) who fill the entire page i think it is heavier to load the image with css.
At least for firefox(20+), if you change tabs or minimize the window and go back again to your page (with the background), i can see that the image takes to show again after a half second.

So, i'm asking bc i found a lot of people telling that basic DOM is better.

Code for css:

```
--html: <body></body>

$('body').css('background', 
"url('http://www.iwallscreen.com/stock/city-lights-hd-wallpaper.jpg') repeat fixed 0 0 #000000");
$('body').css('background-size', "100% auto");
```

Code for canvas:

```
--html: <canvas id="canvasWall" style="position:fixed;left:0;z-index:-1;"></canvas>

var context = $('#canvasWall')[0].getContext("2d");
context.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.iwallscreen.com/stock/city-lights-hd-wallpaper.jpg';   
img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
};
```

Comment: Browsers optimize both canvas and img elements by saving them as bitmaps that they blit through the GPU to video memory.  The browser goes one step further with non-canvas DOM elements by saving the elements on the GPU itself.  This means that once a non-canvas element is rendered once it should be GPU cached and therefore can be displayed more quickly. (A guess without doing tests) I suspect that your minimize/changeTab causes the pre-rendered non-canvas elements to be removed from the GPU--and therefore take longer to redraw because they must be re-saved to the GPU.

Comment: Personally if you designing a website not a canvas application go straight for CSS, if you are going to create a canvas application then use the context.fillRect function, why would you want to use a canvas tag to render the background image in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, canvas: bc of my problem previously shown in firefox (about the "refresh") @markE thats good to know (GPU function for images and canvas), so should i search for the source of the "caching" problem?. also i think i can reduce image/background size with a canvas, in this case image can be easy cached for future use. why the "refresh" problem doesn't happen with canvas? what do you recomend? ty.